# Not escorting NPC in Dragon's Dogma

Tags: dragons-dogma

I currently have an Escort mission in my quest list. I'd like to do other quests without the quest NPC following me around and in danger of dying. Is there any way I can get the NPC to stay in the the city while I complete and clean up other quests on my list?

Comment: You can drop an escort quest by heading back to the quest board you got it from. I'm almost certain they'll be available for pickup again, but there's a waiting involved (and I believe some quest are one-shot, either you complete them or the NPC moves on without you, like when you're supposed to escort the female shop-keeper to the main city.)

Comment: ah ha thank you. the quest was a peddlers petition. got it in gran soren. off the board at the in. i'm assuming that if i check the board again, it will be there.

Comment: usually yes, i do believe there are some that even if obtained from the board can only be picked up once or only at certain points in the progression of the story

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do escort quests is to figure out where they want to go (you can usually find this out in the quest description), then before you grab the quest, go to the finish point and set a port crystal.  Then go back and get the quest.  You can use a ferry stone to port right to the end point and the quest will quickly be completed. You can then pick the port crystal right back up again and re-use it.  The further you get into the game, the more ferrystones/crystals you will find.  Sometimes the shops in Gran Soren will sell ferrystones, too, so be on the lookout.